# Copy 1 TB Google Cloud Storage from container a to b - Run-time?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How long would it on average take to copy files with a total size of 1TB within Google Cloud Storage (Regional Storage) from a container a to b?

e.g. gsutil -m cp gs://gdfp-performance/*.csv gs://gdfp-intrastoragetransfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects are all in the same region and have the same storage class, the operation will only involve changing metadata and the copies won't take any longer regardless of size. In that case, the total size doesn't matter. The main limiting factor is the number of objects.

Regardless, the answer depends tremendously on where you're running the operation from and the characteristics of your network access. You'd probably get optimal performance running it on a large GCE machine in the same region as the data, but again it depends tremendously on how many objects you have, how large they are, and whether you're copying within the same region/class.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful!

It's in the same project, same region, same storage class etc. It's just a copy from container a to container b. 

I've test with difference sizes of GCE. There is no difference, because nothing runs local.
 
I've run it from the Google Cloud Shell and it finally shows the transfer rate of 1 Gib/s so it means ~ 2.5 hours for one TB.

But why does it depend of the size of the GCE when the files are already in GCS?
Is there any solution to improve the copy performance?

Comment: see attached image of 1 GiB/s

Answer (score 0):

Transfer Rate 1 Gib/s - Can performance be improved?[GCS transfer rate 1 GiB/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWGuG.png)